# Execute script not working for https sites - chrome selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to execute a javascript as part of my testing.

Below is my chrome driver settings

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
        options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
        options.addArguments("--reduce-security-for-testing");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://samplesite.com/");
```

And I am trying to execute a script on the site using Javascript executor.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript(code);
```

This is not working due to the below error.

```
The page at 'https://samplesite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/myapi'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

But the same is working when I remove the `headless` option and execute as a visible browser with a Warning message in the console.

could someone guide me on this.

Comment: What is the script that you want to execute?

Comment: The script identified the href elements from the page and post it to my application which is hosted locally.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error stack trace says it all :

```
The page at 'https://samplesite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/myapi'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

The URL `https://samplesite.com/` was loaded with `HTTPS` but the `jquery post script` is trying to call a a webpage over `HTTP`

> **`On an https webpage you can only make Jquery/AJAX Request to https webpage only`**

It would be interesting to know if you are specifying `http` or `https` in the  `Jquery Request`.

You also need to ensure that as the data which you are requesting is not in the same domain, the domain providing the data must allow it with CORS or JSONP.

Comment: Yes. I do understand the issue. As I mentioned in the question. This is executing perfectly well if I am not using the headless option. So I am looking for a solution so that this can work in headless option also.